# Define f: Z/4Z → Z/4Z by f([a]) = [3a+1]

Tags: number-theory, functions, equivalence-relations, formal-proofs

I need to show this function is well defined

For well defined, I was thinking something along the lines of:

**Assume [a1] = [a2] in Z/4Z. Then, a1 is congruent to a2(mod4). So, 4 | a1 - a2. Thus, 4 | 3(a1 - a2) by property of divisibility. Then i can just say 4| 3a1 - 3a2 + 1 -1 which is the same thing as 4| (3a1 +1) - (3a2 +1).**

Right?

How about surjective/injective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to show $4|[(3a_1+1)-(3a_2+1)]$. By your work, you're almost there.

Comment: So I need to show this, or assume. because. I get it if that's what I have to get to. but aside for doing 4 | (3a1 - 3a2) I don't know what else to do. How do you add the 1?

OHH WAIT. Since the 1 - 1 = 0 I can get there can't I?

Like 4 | a1 - a2 ; but 4| 3(a1 -a2) by divisibility rules, but then 4| 3a1 -3a2, but then 4| 3a1 -3a2 +1 -1, but then 4|(3a1 + 1) - (3a2 +1)